# @selector - How to reference a class method?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am adding a menu item programmatically:

`refreshItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Refresh" action:@selector(refreshMenu) keyEquivalent:@""];`

The refreshMenu method is called fine if it's an instance method, but I want to turn it into a class method:
 `+(void)refreshMenu {}`

How would I reference it then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd still use `@selector(refreshMenu)`, but you'd set the `-target` of the `NSMenuItem` to be the `Class` (ie, `[self class]`) instead of the instance (`self`).

Answer (score 1):

Note that classes are objects themselves: they're instances of their metaclass.

```
[menuItem setTarget:[MyClass class]];
```